# How to read data from authorization header in c#

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

Hi I am creating a WEB API and implementing a security mechanism for accessing the API. To access the API a token (GUID) needs to be validated which I am sending as a part of the Authorization header. But while I am reading the header at the API end it is coming encrypted. Can you please help to read the GUID that I have sent to the API as Authorization info.

Following is the code that I am trying:

```
var authorizationInfo = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;
if (authorizationInfo != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationInfo.Scheme))
{
//Guid token = authorizationInfo.Parameter;
}
```

I need to assign the token value GUID format.

Comment: I am not sure I am following. Is your authorization token a GUID (a generated random variation of letters and numbers) or an oauth2 encrypted token?

Comment: Yes @gilmishal: for my case the token is a GUID

Comment: can you show me the http request? and what you're receiving in `authorizationInfo`?